# Appcelerator account stuck in trial after plan purchase?

Tags: package, appcelerator, trial

I just purchased the Indie Monthly Plan but my account seems to remain a free trial account. I tried to sign off and on again but can still see the nagbar at the top in AppceleratorStudio (Dashboard) "... days in Trial Mode - Purchase today!".

Visiting https://billing.appcelerator.com gives me the same "... days in Trial Mode - Purchase today!". But on the very same page "Indie" is marked as my Current Plan.

I have tried with the `appc logout -D` followed by `appc login` but only gets

```
appc config | grep allowProduction
"allowProduction": false,
```

Is there some delay between purchase and system wide update of my user profile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a billing question, and should have been asked directly of Appcelerator support.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it was a matter of waiting.

After a couple of hours the plan was updated and I simply needed to logout Appcelerator Studion (bottom right corner) and close it, run `appc logout` in the terminal and then re-open Appcelerator Studio (and log in).

Comment: It might indeed take a while until the Appcelerator SalesForce has updated the entitlements of the platform. I'll see if we can speed that up.

Comment: NOTE: This is not the best place for questions related to Appcelerator accounts and stuff. Please contact Appcelerator Support instead.